# How to save a downloaded audio file on Android Q with Metadata?

Tags: android, audio, q, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I try to save a downloaded file with the ContentResolver to maintain metadata like artist, album and title.

First question:
Do i need a file with ID3 Tags or is it enough to specify the metadata via the MediaStore?
The MP3 file which gets downloaded doesn't have ID3 Tags.

Second question:
I use the following code to save the mp3 file to the MediaStore:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, audiodata.getTitle());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, audiodata.getArtist());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, audiodata.getAlbum());
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, audiodata.getTitle() + ".mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music/AudioConverter/");

Uri audiouri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
ParcelFileDescriptor file = null;
try {
    file = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(audiouri, "w");
    boolean writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body(), file);
    btnSelectFile.setText("Datei wählen...");
    pbMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    pbMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If I remove the extension ".mp3" from the display name, the Musicplayer shows me the right artist, album and so on. But if I leave the extension as shown above then no metadata gets saved except the display name. 
Is there anything wrong? Do i miss something?

Comment: I'm seeing the same exact issue now. @Nick were you able to find any solutions here?